# DAX IF Contains formula

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

Hi I have a column which contains all windows based OS systems and which type they are so example Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows Server 2000, Windows Server 2003 Standard edition etc.

I need to filter these to only display Windows "name of operating system".

I've used this formula `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("7",[Caption])),"Windows 7","Error")` which picks out all windows 7 but when i try and change "Error" to another IF(ISERROR(SEARCH)) it actually doesn't search the statement correctly.

Any ways i could get round this?
The images below are what happen when i use the formula `
accept
You can nest any formulas in Excel, so replacing "ERROR" with another IF(ISERROR(... is surely possible. Ensure that the formula you want to place is correct by itself and it should work.

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("7",[@Caption])),"Windows 7",IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Windows",[@Caption])), "any other Windows","Error"))`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your last edit is very odd - please see around the `accept` part!

Comment: What is shown in the little exclamation mark next to `Group`header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest any formulas in Excel, so replacing `"ERROR"` with another `IF(ISERROR(...` is surely possible. Ensure that the formula you want to place is correct by itself and it should work.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("7",[@Caption])),
    "Windows 7",
    IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Windows",[@Caption])),
        "any other Windows",
        "Error"))
```

Note that I added and `@` as I think this was missing in your formula!

Comment: Ive tried this way and i get the error "Column '@Caption' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression."

Comment: are you using a table? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Yeah im using a table, and i cant post a screen shot as i done have enough rep to do that

Comment: Ok no worrys ive added images to the main question

Comment: two more questions: The "Group" column is in the same table? Excel 2007 or 2010?

Comment: Yup all in the same table and in Excel 2010, also this is in powerpivot aswell

Comment: Ahh! Now PowerPivot is different, i.e. the formulas - though very similar - are using DAX and not native Excel functions. So, yes, you need to take out the `@`!

Comment: Wouldnt ISNUMBER function work in the same way cause what i've just realized the ISERROR isnt actaully the result i want as in the formula is saying if the error is true its window 7 when im searching for 7 to say if 7 is in text then say its windows 7. Because in a regular excel sheet the ISNUMBER method works

Comment: In the end, ISNUMBER will work the same way as ISERROR - SEARCH will always return either a number or an error, therefore ISNUMBER will be the same as NOT(ISERROR(!

Comment: So, did you try `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("7",[Caption])),"Windows 7",IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("8",[Caption])),"Windows 8","Error"))`?

Comment: Yea i did. I found our that if i use NOT(ISERROR i gave me the answer i was looking for